# Preventing an exe file to stop

Tags: exe

I was messing around with the startup from GTAIV and trying to force it to run in high priority mode without alt-tabbing.

I have made a bat file, which I converted into an exe using 'Iexpress' and named it GTAIV.exe, renamed the original to GTAIV2.exe

My bat file reads:
C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /c start "high" /high "d:\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto IV\GTAIV2.exe"

The exe file works, but here is the problem:

I have to start GTA with the launcher, the second the file 'GTAIV.exe' stops, the launcher ends as well.
The launcher succesfully executes my created exe file though, but the exe stops running when the actual game (GTAIV2.exe) starts, which causes the launcher to end as well, and so giving me an error telling me the game can not run without the launcher.

I was thinking, if I can make my created exe file 'stay alive' (keep running), the launcher will not stop and let me run the game normally.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `/wait` switch when using `start`:

```
...cmd.exe /c start /wait "high" ...
```

Comment: Thank you Greg, that would have worked, if the developers didn't build in an auto-check in the original exe, eventhough the launcher keeps running, I still get the same error. Seems I have no choice but to alt-tab to change priority, oh well at least I gave it my best shot :D